# 405 Ajax POST error

Tags: php, ajax, post, http-status-code-405

So basically my main html page has 3 button with each of them having a different background image linked to it. I'm trying to pass down the source of this image through ajax post to my Php file to write in a txt file.

My JS:

```
// MAIN
$(function() {

$(".artButton").click(function(){
    var artId = $(this).attr("id");
    var source = $("#"+artId).css("background-image").replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1');


    // DEBUG
    console.log(source) //example: http://localhost/crowd.jpg
    console.log(typeof source)//example: string


$.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'writeToTxt.php', 
            data: source,
            success: function(response) {
            console.log("Succes");
    }
});
});
});
```

My Php file:

```
<?php


$my_file = 'toExpose.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data = $_POST['data'];
fwrite($handle, $data);

?>
```

resulting in following error by chrome console:
[405 Ajax Post error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhIpr.png)

Please note that I'm not an expert in programming... More on the "I need something so I'm trying to code it myself"-spectrum. A lot of this might not be best practice in terms of coding but I just need it to work I as expect !
Thanks a lot for the help !

**NOTE**: Everything is running on localhost

**UPDATE**: 
This is the HTML of the page:

```
<html>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<body>
<header class="navbar">
<div class="container">

<h1>Welcome to oneFRAME</h1>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="Home.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Library</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="LibraryV2.html">Library v2</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
</header>



    <button id="choice1" class="artButton" type="button">Nature</button>
    <button id="choice2" class="artButton" type="button">Art</button>
    <button id="choice3" class="artButton" type="button">Crowd</button>


<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="main_temp.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is it laravel??

Comment: Please check permission to 'toExpose.txt' file.

An HTTP 405 error indicates a problem with your script and/or your web server. The error means that you are attempting to pass back a file that does not have the necessary permissions on the server to receive Post information from another script.

Comment: you are using ubantu ?

Comment: what is your web server permissions. issue ls -lh on the directory and send us the permission. you might need to issue chown and chmod on the directory and the files.

Comment: if you're using ubuntu make sure the directory and the files are owned by www-data. #sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /your-dir

Comment: Your question lacks information, such about if there is a framework present or not?

Comment: You need to fix your permission issue first.

Comment: As mentioned I'm totally not familiar with permissions or what so ever. Thus I have no idea what laravel, ubuntu is. I'm doing everything in localhost on my pc. It's to create a prototype so it's not meant to run online. I hope this helps.

Comment: aah, then you need to fix your file permission on your localhost that's running on your pc.

Comment: do you have filezilla ftp? you can set permission through the interface. unless you know how to do it in the code.

Comment: No, I created a local host based on windows internet services. ( a folder somewhere in my C:/ drive). If by permissions you mean the security tab in properties of those files (right click, properties, security), those are all allowed for all users except the "special permissions".

Comment: you need to right click on the c drive folder then set the permission

Comment: I've changed permissions in the wwwroot folder that contains all the html,js and php files. Same error occurs.

Comment: it simple that you just send a url to file based on button click

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 405 error indicates a problem with your script and/or your web server. The error means that you are attempting to pass back a file that does not have the necessary permissions on the server to receive Post information from another script.

Comment: Just added as a note that everything is running on localhost. The txt file doesn't exist up to now as I thought the php would create it one it got fully through

Answer (score 0):

Try passing data in object like

```
$.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'writeToTxt.php', 
            data: {data: source},
            success: function(response) {
            console.log("Succes");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you don't have write permission in htdocs or www directory.

- Change folder permission using `sudo chmod -R 777 /directory`
- Change your ajax method POST to GET (sometime not work with).

Not sure but I have doubt your path must be http://localhost/example/index.php

**Updated Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <button id="choice1" class="artButton" type="button" style="background-image:url('http://localhost/Veridocglobalportal2/veridocedu/public/img/edu-logo.png');">Nature</button>
    <button id="choice2" class="artButton" type="button">Art</button>
    <button id="choice3" class="artButton" type="button">Crowd</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // MAIN
$(function() {

$(".artButton").click(function(){
    var artId = $(this).attr("id");
     var source = $("#"+artId);
switch (artId) {
    case "choice1":
        var source = "http://localhost/crowd.jpg";
        break;
    case "choice2":
        var source = "http://localhost/people.jpg";
        break;
    case "choice3":
        var source = "http://localhost/alone.jpg";
        break;
 }


// DEBUG
console.log(source) //example: http://localhost/crowd.jpg
console.log(typeof source)//example: string

$.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'writeToTxt.php', 
            data: {"data":source},
            success: function(response) {
            console.log("Succes");
    }
});
});
});
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**writeTotxt.php**

```
   <?php
$cwd=getcwd();
$data = $_POST['data'];
$myfile = file_put_contents("$cwd/logs.txt", $data.PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );
```

Comment: I changed the url of the php to http://localhost/writeToTxt.php. But I still get the 405 error. Regarding the permissions, as i'm working on  windows localhost, I've changed the permissions of the folder wherein all my files are to allow all changes.

Comment: is file available in location?

Comment: @Stas06 artButton is button or image?

Comment: var source = $("#"+artId).css("background-image").replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1');
what will be path?

Comment: artButton is a class I gave to the buttons to use .this in the js

Comment: can I have output of source variable?

Comment: the debug section is the output of the source variable :)

Comment: This issue is regarding source variable you should give $1 and that

Comment: html of artButton tag needed if you can add in question

Comment: HTML is added in the update of the main post, hope this helps

Comment: source are always none.

Comment: Because you don't have the images I suppose when I print out the debug section I get following in the chrome console: https://scontent-bru2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/39467662_1793387010698520_6862261577454714880_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=734c578f86c2c449f7863889a68ff689&oe=5C0B4724

Comment: The background images I have are in css. I the variable source changed every time i pressed one of the buttons. It's always a string but the path is different when I click the button. I copied your php but I still get same issue 405 method not allowed

Comment: what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {

$(".artButton").click(function(){
  var artId = $(this).attr("id");
  var source = $("#"+artId).css("background-image").replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1');


// DEBUG
console.log(source) //example: http://localhost/crowd.jpg
console.log(typeof source)//example: string


$.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',  
        url: 'writeToTxt.php', 
        data: {source:source},
        success: function(response) {
          console.log("Succes");
        }
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: jQuery code is seems correct you need to check server file setting. first check writeToTxt.php permission after see the allow method validation.
find here 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#405

Answer (score -1):

You are getting client side error.
4.x.x is all about client side errors.

Change your ajax request like this -

```html
$.ajax({  
                type: 'POST',  
                url: 'writeToTxt.php', 
                data: 'name=xxx&address=xxxx',
                success: function(response) {
                console.log("Succes");
        }
    });
```

replace 'name=xxx&address=xxxx' with your post data.

and in PHP use like this -
$name = $_POST['name'];
$adress = $_POST['address'];